# UIScrollView with UITapGestureRecognizer and UIPageControl

Tags: iphone, scrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipagecontrol

I'm creating a **horizontal scrolling tableview containing images**.  I have the swiping functionality working great, and am able to add the images to the `scrollView` as so in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tv.frame.size.width, 78)];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(700, 78)];
    UIImage *footImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Foot.png"];
    UIImageView *footImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:footImage];
    footImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 78);
    footImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [scrollView addSubview: footImageView];

    UIImage *handImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hand.png"];
    UIImageView *handImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:handImage];
    handImageView.frame = CGRectMake(90, 0, 80, 78);
    handImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [scrollView addSubview: handImageView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(highlightImage)];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    NSLog(@"tapGesture added to scrollView");


    [[cell contentView] addSubview:scrollView];

    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, tv.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [pageControl setNumberOfPages:4];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:pageControl];
```

My `tapGesture` is registering with the selector, `hightlightImage`, and just logging that its calling this method correctly.

```
- (void) highlightImage
{
    NSLog(@"tapping tapping");
}
```

What I **REALLY** am working for is the ability to **highlight/select** these images if tapped, and **highlight/deselect** them if tapped again.  I will have another button on screen that will navigate to the next page (irrelevant here).

Am I going down the right path here? Obviously I will populate an `NSArray` of `UIImages` and populate the `scrollView` that way, but just spiking it out for now.  If someone could give me some direction or an example of how to make each button **separately** selectable/de-selectable, that would be GREAT:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UIButton instead of UIImageView.

It's got built-in `selected` functionality.

get rid of your gestures and add highlightImage as the action to every button.

make your `highlightImage` into `highlightImage:(id)sender`

sender should be a button so you can just do

[sender setSelected:YES];

Comment: Boom! I had already migrated to use UIButtons, but didnt even think to use each button's action for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.  My new `highlightImage` method is picking up the different senders it is sent (Each `UIButton` instance).

Now,Im using a method `createScrollButtons` to create each button in its desired location along the scrollview.  I will have to call `addTarget: action: forControlEvents:` for EACH button that I want to create.  What Id really like is a loop of some sort, so go over each `UIButton` desired to create and place them in the correct location along the scrollView.